# Where do I set the project name used on screen for multiple accounts login?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-account

I've got a GAE app which uses `users.create_login_url()` to redirect users toward oauth2 login. Using it puts up a screen like this.

[image: google multiple accounts login]

Question is:

How to change "My Project" to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to application settings on appengine.google.com and set "Application Title" (Displayed if users authenticate to use your application.)

[image]

Comment: oh, wow, so there is an `appengine` console as well as a `developers` console!?

Comment: yeah, but it will be deprecated in the future, but some features still not available in developers console.

Comment: I _think_ what you want is in the new Developer Console under **APIs & Auth > Consent Screen** - it would be good to know!

Comment: @tx802 looks like it depends on which oauth you are using -- new one with google+ sign-in, or old one.